# Is a 99% confidence level more precise than 95%?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

[image]

Hi.
I'm confused by 'significance level'.
If significance level is lower, is the result of test more reliable? I think it's the opposite, so it makes me so confused.

Look at the picture and assume that $H_0$ is null hypothesis, $\alpha$ is the 'significance level'.
Let's test this, by sample size is 40, as a result sample mean is $\mu_1$.
If the given 'confidence level'($1-\alpha$) is 95%, z value of 'c' would be 1.96. 
If given 99%, 'c' would be 2.56

Here is the problem.
If confidence level is 99%, is the result more reliable than confidence level 95%?
If c level is 99%, more error would be included in null hypothesis area, than level 95%.
if c level is 99%, it means '99% of deviation would be regarded as in the null area anyway. So actually, c level 99% means it's less precise than 95%, right?
Rather, if confidence level is very small like 5%, so the 'c' value goes closer to $\mu_0$, it would mean that we will regard more values to be error. So it must be more precise.

Am I wrong? The textbook seems to say i'm wrong. And hope you genius explain it..
Thank you!

Comment: If you are saying for example with 95% confidence that you think the mean is below $59.6$ and with 99% confidence you the mean is below $65.6$, then the second (wider) confidence interval is more likely to cover the actual mean leading to the greater confidence.  The second approach reduces the probability of wrongly rejecting the null hypothesis, but it is a less precise estimate and increases the probability of wrongly failing to reject the null hypothesis

Comment: How do you think about this problem? that I wrote below. [[ The text book says, "social science phenomenon has bigger deviation, so use bigger α, 0.05 . On contrary, nature science phenomenon has less deviation, so use smaller α, 0.001". Here is my question. Why nature science regard more exceptional cases as 'null area' than social science? Even Though they say "nature science has less deviation"? Shouldn't it be reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should know that 'test' is focused on if we can 'reject', rather than 'adopt'.
So the Confidence Level is about the accuracy of rejection, not adoption.

So if we raise confidence level from 95% to 99%, the rejection area becomes smaller.
And if the test result is in the rejection area though, we can more confidently reject the null hypothesis. It can be more reliable than rejection from 95% confidence level, because 95% CL has wider rejection area, thus more possibility to 'not reject' wrong fact.

Seems it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ is the probability that we make the error of the first kind (we reject the hypothesis although it is true). The test is of course more reliable (in the case the hypothesis is rejected) , if $\alpha$ is smaller. (confidence level is $1-\alpha$ and this is then larger).

However , usually the probability to make the error of the second kind (we accept the hypothesis although it is wrong) increases, if $\alpha$ decreases. So, in practice $\alpha$ is not chosen too small to have a good realibility in both cases.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
But I still have a curiosity.

Please check if my understand is wrong.

If null hyp is true, the mean is $\mu0$. And if we take samples from it, it will show the deviation of graph H0.
 Value 'c' means, "if the sample is so far from mean, bigger than c, we can't say it is possible shape of $\mu0$. So, we will regard it as error. It means, Null hyp may not be true".

Comment: In this view, if 'c' moves to right side, much far from $\mu0$, it means "more exceptional cases will be regarded as possible shape of Null hyp.". It means, if I say "I'll still stick to Null hyp", it can be less precise.
 In a word, less $\alpha$, less precise.
Isn't this right?

Comment: The larger $c$ (and therefore the smaller $\alpha$) , the larger must be the deviation of the expected result to lead to a rejection. So, you are right that more exceptional cases are regarded as possible. And this means that the probability $\beta$ for the error of the second kind increases.

Comment: I almost understood what this means thanks to you.
However, I have still curiosity.
The text book says, "social science phenomenon has bigger deviation, so use bigger $\alpha$, 0.05 .  On contrary,  nature science  phenomenon has less deviation, so use smaller $\alpha$, 0.001". Here is my question.  Why nature science regard more exceptional cases as 'null area' than social science? Even Though they say "nature science has less deviation"? Shouldn't it be reverse?

Comment: What they probably mean that many physical phenomens can be measured with high precision (the error is usually small) whereas social phenomena are far more arbitary. However, $\alpha$ depends on the critical region (which we can adjust for a chosen error probability) , so I do not agree to this statement.

Comment: Ok ~ thank you very much!